# RhoMobile Javascript App - How to change between pages

Tags: javascript, rhomobile

I'm building a RhoMobile app using Javascript, not Ruby. I wanted to find out what the correct way is to open a new page (html file) from a page button or link? There's not much documentation on this.

I tried Window.location but that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone provide a hint?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I used the statement below which seems to work.

```
Rho.WebView.navigate('/public/map.html');
```